# PHP and Golang sha512 different result

Tags: php, symfony, go, base64

I wanted to implement the Symfony password hash in Golang. The result is the same expect some character.

The Symfony solution:

```
function mergePasswordAndSalt($password, $salt)
{
    return $password.'{'.$salt.'}';
}

$salted = mergePasswordAndSalt('asd12345', 'korsipcidz4w84kk0cccwo840s8s4sg');
$digest = hash('sha512', $salted, true);


for ($i = 1; $i < 5000; ++$i) {
    $new = $digest.$salted;
    $digest = hash('sha512', $new, true);
}

echo base64_encode($digest);
```

The Golang solution:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha512"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "hash"
)

var (
    hasher    hash.Hash
    container []byte
)

func main() {
    password := "asd12345"
    salt := "korsipcidz4w84kk0cccwo840s8s4sg"
    salted := []byte(password + "{" + salt + "}")

    hasher = sha512.New()
    hasher.Write(salted)
    container = hasher.Sum(nil)

    for i := 1; i < 5000; i++ {
        new := append(container[:], salted[:]...)

        hasher = sha512.New()
        hasher.Write(new)
        container = hasher.Sum(nil)
    }
    digest := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(container)
    fmt.Println(digest)
}
```

The Golang result:

```
yIp0074qTaxBz7fOGFpTVYU7LaAterUko6YjnmCZ55R6lAYouXWFoBKT_wI7Vit87RKbU9I-U3M2mU11v_KEUQ==
```

The PHP result:

```
yIp0074qTaxBz7fOGFpTVYU7LaAterUko6YjnmCZ55R6lAYouXWFoBKT/wI7Vit87RKbU9I+U3M2mU11v/KEUQ==
```

So how the example shown, it is the same just some other character lik -,/,+ are the different. I think it can be because of the character coding, but I haven't idea, how can I determine it. 
Environment: Fedora 23, Go 1.7, PHP 5.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `URLEncoding`, while PHP seems to use standard encoding. Replace

```
digest := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(container)
```

with

```
digest := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(container)
```

and it issues the same results as PHP: https://play.golang.org/p/6pHCN6rb9U.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. However, any of the solutions posted didn't work.

I resolved by using a hex package.

```
import "encoding/hex"

checkSum := sha512.New() 
checkSum.Write([]byte(password + salt)) 
checkSumStr := hex.EncodeToString(checkSum.Sum(nil))
```